# Ruby creating binary data from human readable

Tags: ruby, ipv6, packet

I am creating a variable that is the payload of an IPv6 packet, and I need to have multiple data formats concatenated to it, and am having some trouble.

Specifically, I have:

```
64 - unsigned int 1 byte (prefix length)
1100 0000 - binary 1 byte (flags)
86400 - unsigned int, left padded/4 bytes (lifetime)
14400 - unsigned int, left padded/4 bytes (preferred lifetime)
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 - reserved/unused 4 bytes
```

New to ruby - anything will help.

Comment: Are you receiving the values above in ASCII format and need to pack them? Or are the values you show binary and you are displaying them in the format you want? There's not nearly enough information.

Comment: Also, this sounds suspiciously like a homework exercise. If it is please let us know.

Comment: I added ipv6 and packet tags to make the question more visible.

Comment: I am creating the contents from scratch. So, how it is displayed above is the format I have them - essentially human readable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002222)? That's probably what you'll need to build your packets.

Comment: somewhat familiar with pack, but things like: >> [ 64 ].pack("I")
=> "@\000\000\000" dont really work when I need 1 byte vs 4...